# Is it possible to purchase a wireless ergonomic solar keyboard?

Tags: keyboards, ergonomics, solar-power

I have an ergonomic keyboard that I like, and I have a solar keyboard that I like.  I would like to purchase a (preferably wireless) keyboard that is a combination of these two, but I haven't been able to find one.

I have tried Amazon, Best Buy, and PriceGrabber, but no luck.

Does such a thing exist?  Can it be purchased?

UPDATE:  I will use the keyboard with my laptop, when I am at my desk.  This is to avoid carpal tunnel syndrome from using the cramped laptop keyboard (something I have seen happen to coworkers).  The advantage of solar is 1) not having to change batteries, 2) not having to pay for batteries or that (admittedly tiny) use of electricity when plugged in, and 3) not having to fill the landfill with dead batteries.

Comment: What feature of a solar powered keyboard appeals to your application? One might expect that your use is on a portable outside device? Consider to edit your question to provide indication of application. You are correct about the difficulty of finding one. Plenty of solar powered, plenty of ergonomic, none combined, even the compilations of "best..." products come up empty

Comment: I am not sure how having to put the keyboard in the sun every few days is going to be better than changing batteries once a year ?  A solar rechargable device also has batteries, normally lithium which are worse for the environment.